# Encrypting Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, encryption

I am trying to encrypt my core data.

As suggested in another question, I have read through the following post from Nick Harris https://nickharris.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/core-data-and-enterprise-iphone-applications-protecting-your-data/.

Firstly on my device, I turned on my passcode in settings.

Then in my appDelegate, when I am creating my persistentStoreCoordinator, I add the following attribute NSFileProtectionComplete to my core data store file which to my understanding would mean that when the device is passcode locked, my core data should be encrypted or not accessible.

```
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:fileAttributes ofItemAtPath:[storeURL path] error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Cant encrypt");
    }
```

However, having done all this, even with the device passcode locked, I can still access the apps sandbox and the documents folder containing the .sqllite file using iExplorer and I can take the whole file onto my desktop and view it all completely unencrypted.

Am I missing something??

Comment: anybody got any ideas about this?

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone is interested, I figured out why I stupidly thought the encryption provided by apple as mentioned in my question was not working....
I was turning on the encryption on my CoreData file and to test I was simply trying to grab the .sqlLite file from my device using iExplorer..It appeared to be accessing the file because the .sqlLite file opened using my sqlLite browser. However it was not actually opening the latest file from the device but instead was opening a cached version of the file...

Comment: Spot on. Had the same issue.